# Get username in WCF service from web client on Windows and Citrix

Tags: javascript, wcf, web, operating-system

My current project constists of 2 components:

- a WCF server application
- a purely client-sided (javascript, jQuery, TypeScript etc) website which consumes the service.

When the client saves data to my database via the WCF service, I need to log who made the last modification to that data.
To do this I need the username of the account the client website's browser is running under.
Browser support needs to be:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- IE 10/11.

I don't want to create a login form for my website, I want the user to be able to open the website and be logged on using their Windows/Citrix account.

Javascript can't get to the account username because of security concerns obviously.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have a experimental answer for you. Not sure but posible to work correctly. I think, you can activate impersonation and basic authentication on iis. Then client(browsers) ask credentials  to client. In service layer, you can enable impersonation too. but only iis impersonation may enough.